# Python: lists as pointers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pointers

From C I learned to love (and hate) pointers. I was wondering if there was a general way to work with pointers to arbitrary objects in python.

From what I have read it seems not possible or at least it does not seem like Python is intended to work with pointers. However you could use the fact that lists work like pointers in python

```
pointer_to_integer = [1]

def add_func(x, y):
    x[0]+= y

add_func(pointer_to_integer, 1)
print(pointer_to_integer)

>>> [2]
```

My questions are: How bad is it to exploit this? Are there any caveats? Why should I not be doing this?

Comment: There are surelly good technical reasons, but the first that pops in my brain is: "_Readability counts._".

Comment: I would not suggest trying to force Python to act like C, because it's just going to result in code that is both confusing and sub-optimal. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is good and bad at the same time. The good reason is you don't have to work with those `*` and `&` like in C, the bad reason is you might change the variable unintentionally.

Comment: The arguments against this are pretty much a subset of "why are impure functions less preferable than pure functions?"

Comment: How about `class P: def __init__(self, data): self.data = data`? This way, at least it's kindof clear that it's supposed to be a "pointer" of sorts.

Comment: It's sometimes useful to do that sort of thing (eg, when you have a 2D array that you want to be able to access via rows and via columns), but generally it's better to avoid it, since the extra level of indirection adds clutter to the code, and impacts efficiency. Bottom line: don't try to write C in Python.